# Will taking sponsorships I can't fulfill hurt my marketability?

Tags: motorsport-manager

[image]

I'm on a team with little hopes of a points finish, let alone "2nd or above." Still, that 1.25€ million upfront looks too enticing to pass.

If I take on such a sponsorship but fail to meet the target, will my marketability be hurt?

Comment: I didn't know when I posted this question that [you can only have one active sponsor objective](https://i.imgur.com/Tkz6H2Z.png)